# GitHub Actions: CodeQL Analysis results

Tags: github-actions, codeql

I have integrated CodeQL in my github project via website. It works, it analyses and produce SARIF files. And then it says that results were successfully uploaded:

```
Uploading results
  Processing sarif files: ["/home/runner/work/my_project/results/cpp-builtin.sarif"]
  Uploading results
  Successfully uploaded results
```

Where? Where I can find these results and read them? How CodeQL indicates that there are issues found?
My .yaml contains:

```
    - run: |
       sudo -n apt-get install -y autopoint gettext
       autoreconf --install
       ./configure
       make
    - name: Perform CodeQL Analysis
      uses: github/codeql-action/analyze@v1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GitHub repository -> Security tab -> Code scanning alerts

[GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secure-coding/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/managing-code-scanning-alerts-for-your-repository#viewing-the-alerts-for-a-repository)